# Inspection for unnecessary repeated getters; and setter followed by getter

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection

There is several good practice issues IntelliJ help us, for instance, replacing `for (o : a) {...}` by `forEach` with `lambda`, indicating unnecessary variables or simplifying operations...

But there is something really bothers me: doing consecutives repeated getters, for instance:

```
String street = form.getPerson().getAddress().getStreet();
String city = form.getPerson().getAddress().getCity();
String state = form.getPerson().getAddress().getState();
```

I usually replace it for:

```
Address address = form.getPerson().getAddress();
String street = address.getStreet();
String city = address.getCity();
String state = address.getState();
```

I found it pretty cleaner.

Or then getters following setter:

```
form.setPerson(new Person());
form.getPerson().setPhone(phone);
form.getPerson().setEmail(email);
```

I usually replace it for:

```
Person person = new Person();
form.setPerson(person);
person.setPhone(phone);
person.setEmail(email);
```

Even if there is just one getter after the setter I do it, I found it better.

I do it manually every time I see these patterns, I wonder if there are more people who agrees with me, and if there is some way to IntelliJ helps me with it. Or how to describe this problem to make a suggestion for them.

P.S.: Remember, there are a risk when doing it after a call, for instance:

```
Address address = form.getPerson().getAddress();
address.setStreet("foo");
this.someMethodCall(form);
// The following assertion may be false
Assert.assertEquals(address.getStreet(), form.getPerson().getAddress().getStreet());
// As well as the following, since the method call has the form instance, so that it could change the address or even the person.
Assert.assertEquals(address, form.getPerson().getAddress());
```

But I want to take that risk.

Comment: In general, you can't make this transformation, because each call to `form.getPerson()` or `Person.getAddress()` might mutate state, so calling it three times has different semantics to calling it once and caching the variable. Of course, if they are "plain old getters", which don't mutate state, this isn't a problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know, for instance when using Hibernate, but even so, I don't see the need of doing consecutive getters, I hate it, I would do it only when strictly necessary.